# Why two O(n) programs are same? Do constants matter?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complexity. Why dont constants matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106538/complexity-why-dont-constants-matter)

I have a simple question regarding complexity of a code/algorithm. I understand the basic complexity concepts pretty well, such as order of growth with respect to input, why O(n) is better than O(n^2) etc. However, I am not sure if constants really matter or not because it seems to me that they should but no one ever considers them or talks about them. Can you improve a code with same complexity. Lets say I have a code with some order complexity lets say O(n). Lets say this code runs in 10 mins for certain input. What if I repeat the code twice and now the code runs in 20 mins. 20 mins over 10 mins is a big deal although the complexity is the same. Do these things matter or not, regardless of identical complexity? If not why? If yes, why? Please explain.

Comment: What do you mean by repeat code twice?

Comment: I meant doing the same task twice to reach the result.

Answer (score 4):

In theoretical complexity analysis, coefficients do not matter at all. In practice, they matter a great deal. This is why almost everyone still uses the (exponential complexity) simplex algorithm instead of (polynomial complexity) interior point algorithms for optimization problems.

If you're doing algorithm analysis and want to know the O() behavior, then constants are irrelevant. If you want to know which piece of code will run faster for a particular range of problems, then everything matters.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that it's not quite the *constants* that make the difference in simplex. Rather, it's the difference between generic-case complexity and worst-case complexity that's the real difference.

Comment: @Mehrdad - but the constants do matter. For sufficiently large problems, interior point code is actually better. The constants (which depend on the details of the implementation as well as the algorithmic structure) determine the break-even point.

Comment: Ah that's very true, good point.

Comment: @Mehrdad - You do have a good point, though, that worst-case behavior (as characterized by the O() function) can sometimes be a very poor predictor of average case behavior for a particular application of the algorithm(s).

Answer (score 3):

I think you are mixing the real concept of complexity with different example of performance. By complexity, what we mean is: **if n grows, what is the order of processing steps growth.**

Say for example, you are performing linear search and your order in this case is O(n). What des it mean here that: if n = 5, and it takes 5 seconds then for n=10, it will take 10 seconds i.e. relationship is linear.

It doesn't make difference, if order was O(5n) i.e. you same search takes 25 seconds for n=5, then for n=10, it will take 50 seconds. I can still say, its O(n) i.e. directly dependent.

Same example goes with sort algorithms who are O(n^2).

In your example, **the mentioned improvement does matter** but it doesn't change the order of complexity i.e. the relationship. If we can reduce the processing time by two times, **it's a big improvement** provided `n` is a high number e.g. time was reduced from 20 minutes to 10 minutes. If you change you algorithm to alter the relationship of time taken with the grown of n, then O(n) will also changed :)

Answer (score 1):

> It does not matter for complexity theory, which is interested only in
>   how the function scales as the input size grows.
>
> A constant does not affect how the function behaves as input sizes
>   grow towards infinity at all.
>
> However, if you are interested in actually running a certain piece of
>   code, you may very well be interested in a large constant overhead and
>   how the function performs for smaller input sizes.
>
> Difference between complexity theory and practice.

This is a good answer on this question.

[Complexity. Why dont constants matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106538/complexity-why-dont-constants-matter)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it matters if you make an algorithm that's twice as slow as it needs to be.  The point is, we care about an algorithm's performance in terms of "n", because "n" has the potential to be very big.

Let's take a practical example.  Say you have a list of n items.  Your algorithm iterates through the list once.  That's order n.  If it iterates over the list twice, that will likely take longer, and it's slower - you shouldn't do that if it's unnecessary.

But having an n^2 algorithm has a much bigger impact in the long run than a 2*n algorithm.  As n gets bigger and bigger, the difference between n^2 and 2*n gets larger and larger.

So to answer your question, yes, it matters when a program runs twice as slow.  But it matters a lot more if it is exponentially slower.  That's why we care about Big-Oh.  But any improvement to the speed will obviously be good for your program.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much a difference between theory and practice. There are some points to consider for this:

- The constants may not be clear for real implementation. You cannot usually determine those constants from a given implementation. Lets for Example say you have two O(N) algorithms for the same Problem, one however needs 2N operations and the second needs only N operations. One might assume that the one with N operations runs faster, but this may not be the case. We may have 2N operations which only take 1 cycle each because of better cache or pipline usage etc, whereas the other algorithm may take N operations with 4 cycles each. So the algorithm with more operations may still be faster. On a different hardware this may look very different. So unless you know the exact hardware the theoretical analysis is a very good guide. On real hardware usually the interactions are so intricate, that only benchmarking will give you a good hint.
- For real time systems, again the situation is a lot different. Here one is usually interested in the Worst Case Execution Time (WCET), which refers to the actual time an algorithm may take. In this case constants do matter a lot. However in this case also the problem size is known (usually a set of inputs from a couple of sensors), so the analysis is a lot different.
- The influence of the hardware can get so big, that an algorithm, which looks worse in theory, may actually outperform an algorithm which looks much better, at least for all relevant problem sizes. This is often the case for algorithms which use trees (often better in theory) vs. algorithm which use flat array structures (often worse in theory). Usually a flat array is better of however, as it can be cached much more efficiently. Sometimes it is possible to use the best of both worlds however, for example when implementing a heap as an array (this almost always outperforms sorted trees).

Answer (score 0):

When comparing O(n) with O(n^2)  as n grows constants will start becoming irrelevant. That should be pretty obvious even if constants are large.

The reason why constants are not mentioned is that the order of complexity is more important. Once you know an algorithm is linear time you go and check the slope yourself while working out the details.

When you have two programs that are O(n) constants will matter in deciding which is better. Then you have to analyze the algorithms in more detail.